# Color glitch with tilemap.SetColor() in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, tilemap, tiles

I've been experimenting with Tilemap to display tiles (with random colors) in script with SetColor() and other methods:

```
x = tilemap.WorldToCell(cur);  

tilemap.SetTile(x, tile);
tilemap.SetTileFlags(x, TileFlags.None);
tilemap.SetColor(x, UtilityFunc.GetRandColor());
```

But as the number of tiles increased to a certain point, the colors just glitched out (this is a 200x400 hexagon, pointed-top grid):

[image]

Full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class TEST : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Tilemap tilemap;
    [SerializeField] Tile tile;

    [Space(15)]
    [SerializeField] private float hexSize = 0.1f;

    [Space(15)]
    [SerializeField] private int hexLevel = 20;
    [SerializeField] private int perLevel = 20;

    private float hexWidth, hexHeight;
    [SerializeField] private float delay = 0.2f;

    Vector3Int x;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreatBoard());
    }

    IEnumerator CreatBoard()
    {
        tilemap.transform.localScale = new Vector3(hexSize, hexSize, 1f);
        hexHeight = hexSize; hexWidth = hexHeight/2f * Mathf.Sqrt(3f);

        bool goLeft = true; Vector2 original = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
        original += new Vector2(-hexWidth*perLevel/2f, hexLevel*hexHeight*0.75f/2f);

        //create board
        for (int i = 0; i < hexLevel; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
            original = (goLeft) ? GetBottomLeftPos(original) : GetBottomRightPos(original); goLeft = !goLeft; Vector2 cur = original;
            for (int j = 0; j < perLevel; j++)
            {
                x = tilemap.WorldToCell(cur);

                tilemap.SetTile(x, tile);
                tilemap.SetTileFlags(x, TileFlags.None);
                tilemap.SetColor(x, UtilityFunc.GetRandColor());

                cur = GetRightPos(cur);
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector2 GetTopRightPos(Vector2 pos) { return new Vector2(pos.x + hexWidth/2, pos.y + hexHeight*0.75f); }
    private Vector2 GetTopLeftPos(Vector2 pos) { return new Vector2(pos.x - hexWidth/2, pos.y + hexHeight*0.75f); }

    private Vector2 GetLeftPos(Vector2 pos) { return new Vector2(pos.x - hexWidth, pos.y); }
    private Vector2 GetRightPos(Vector2 pos) { return new Vector2(pos.x + hexWidth, pos.y); }

    private Vector2 GetBottomRightPos(Vector2 pos) { return new Vector2(pos.x + hexWidth/2, pos.y - hexHeight*0.75f); }
    private Vector2 GetBottomLeftPos(Vector2 pos) { return new Vector2(pos.x - hexWidth/2, pos.y - hexHeight*0.75f); }
}
```

And random color function:

```
public static Color GetRandColor()
{
    return new Color(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f),
        UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f),
        UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f),
    1f);
}
```

Why is the Tilemap system behaving like this?

Additional info: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiGuvdMFaQg)

Comment: Can you give us a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, including the implementations of all functions like GetRightPos and GetRandColor?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, let me edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Since the C++ source code of Unity is not public, what I am talking about here is **speculation**

From the video, the wrong part of the tile color changes together. There must be some kind of resource limit. To save memory, tilemap has some [flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)-like design. This means that instead of each tile having its own complete resource, there is something like a resource index. Such as sprites and colors.

Just like:

```
HashTable<int,Color> _colorTable;
void SetTileColor(Vector3Int position, Color color){
    int colorKey = GetColorKey(color);
    Tile tile = GetTile(position);
    tile.colorIndex = colorKey;
}
int GetColorKey(Color color){
    int colorKey = some_hash_strategy(color);
    if(_colorTable.CoutainsKey(colorKey)){
        return colorKey;
    }
    if(_colorTable.Count >= COLOR_NUM_MAX){
        //ooops! color run out, I'll just give you the last one, what ever
        colorKey = lastColorKey;
    }
    _colorTable[colorKey]=color;
    return colorKey;
}
```

Proof: Compare the memory addresses of the colors returned by `tilemap.GetColor`. The color passed in when `tilemap.SetColor` is called is all new object, but `tilemap.GetColor` returned some duplicate addresses.:-)

Fix: Limit the number of colors so that color resources do not run out.

```
private Color GetRandColor()
{
    return new Color(randFloat(), randFloat(), randFloat(), 1f);
}
private float randFloat()
{
    return Random.Range(0, 16) / 16f;
}
```